# Difference in two coding snippets

Tags: java

I am practicing Java using [CodingBat Java](http://codingbat.com/prob/p140449). I am currently working on this problem here:

> We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is
> talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return true if we are in
> trouble.
>
> ```
> parrotTrouble(true, 6) → true
> parrotTrouble(true, 7) → false
> parrotTrouble(false, 6) → false
> ```

My code that I put in is different than the expected answer. But as I look at the expected answer, I am trying to figure out why my answer is not acceptable. It is a trivial question, but I am rusty in Java. Can anyone care to take a look and tell me why my answer is not accepted or if their is a problem with the code that I am not catching?

My code:

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
  for (hour = 0; hour <= 23; hour++)
  {
     if(hour < 7 || hour > 20)
     {
        talking = true;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
  return talking;
}
```

Expected Answer:

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
  return (talking && (hour < 7 || hour > 20));
  // Need extra parenthesis around the || clause
  // since && binds more tightly than ||
  // && is like arithmetic *, || is like arithmetic +
}
```

Comment: how is parrotTrouble(false, 6) false and true at the same time?

Comment: you are not reading the value of `talking`...

Comment: @bot, this is the problem that CodingBat Java has set up.

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no sense for this assignment. Why are you using a loop here? Why do you change the value of talking?

Comment: I am ASKING this because i am rusty in Java, as I mentioned in the question!

Comment: @ryekayo I suggest you used a debugger to run your code step by step and understand what it does - you should quickly see why it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function takes two arguments, `talking` and `hour`. The first thing your code does is set `hour` to 0. This means your code completely ignores one of it's arguments when deciding what value should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

- It is not acceptable simply because there is way too much lines for what it does, which make it harder to read.
- It is not acceptable because you don't have to loop over all hours, your already know them, but instead of using the correct values, you set the hour to 0, and loop until 23.

Note that there is no point in writing

```
if(boolean)
{
    boolean = true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
return boolean;
```

when you can simply write `return boolean`

Also the first case does not validate that `talking` is set to true when comparing while the second case does.

Your codewill always return false as you will loop from 0 to 23, which mean you will return false when you will reach 8.

Answer (score 1):

The differences in your code...

1. There is no need to iterate (with the `for` loop)
2. You are trying to change the value `talking` and `hour` input parameters. You should just be reading these.
3. You never *read* the `talking` or `hour` input parameter.

You really only need to do **two** things...

1. Check to see if the parrot is talking. If he isn't talking, then you are never in trouble. 
   `if(talking)`
2. If he is talking, then check to see if the current hour is in the range of time that will cause trouble. 
   `if(hour < 7 || hour >20)`

Comment: Addition: 2. and 3. also apply for `hour`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code. First and foremost is that your code is not doing what it is supposed to do. Your code should return if you are in trouble or not. What your code does is to return whether or not the parrot is talking.

Also, it looks like your code will always return `false`. Why? Because you are iterating all the hours of the day. When your for-loop arrives at `hour == 7` it is neither `< 7` nor `> 20`. Therefor your `if` statement will `return false`.

You are supposed to create a boolean expression that simply checks if the given value `hour` is smaller than 7 or greater than 20:

```
return (hour < 7 || hour > 20)
```

In addition you are supposed to check if the parrot is actually talking. This information is represented by the first method parameter `talking`.

So:

```
return (is the parrot talking and is the hour smaller than 7 or greater than 20)
```

Translates to:

```
return (talking && (hour < 7 || hour > 20));
```